# Define vue component in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, ref

I'm using VueJS to load my data in view (using Laravel).  I do register my components in app.js file, and when I want to use them in one of my blade files it gives me this error:

> (unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.)

My app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});

Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
   'passport-authorized-clients',
   require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
   'passport-personal-access-tokens',
   require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

Vue.component('employer-enquiry-names', 
require('./components/Employer/Enquiry/Edit/Names.vue'));
Vue.component('employer-enquiry-users', 
require('./components/Employer/Enquiry/Edit/Users.vue'));
Vue.component('employer-enquiry-employer', 
require('./components/Employer/Enquiry/Edit/Employer.vue'));
```

And here I used my component:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="enquiry_tabs">
   <employer-enquiry-employer ref="employer_enquiry_employer">

  </employer-enquiry-employer>

  <employer-enquiry-users ref="employer_enquiry_users">
  </employer-enquiry-users>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="names">
       <employer-enquiry-names ref="employer_enquiry_names" >
        </employer-enquiry-names>
   </div>
 </div>



 <script>
     var vm = new Vue({ el: '#enquiry_tabs' });
     vm.$refs.employer_enquiry_employer.loadData();
     $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
         var activatedTab = e.target; // activated tab
         if (activatedTab.id == "names_link") {
            vm.$refs.employer_enquiry_names.loadData();
         } else if (activatedTab.id == "users_link") {
            vm.$refs.employer_enquiry_users.loadData();
         } else if (activatedTab.id == "employer_link") {
             vm.$refs.employer_enquiry_employer.loadData();
         }
      });
  </script>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Register the vue components before you instantiate your root vue instance

```
    require('./bootstrap');

// register components

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
   'passport-authorized-clients',
   require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
   'passport-personal-access-tokens',
   require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

Vue.component('employer-enquiry-names', 
require('./components/Employer/Enquiry/Edit/Names.vue'));
Vue.component('employer-enquiry-users', 
require('./components/Employer/Enquiry/Edit/Users.vue'));
Vue.component('employer-enquiry-employer', 
require('./components/Employer/Enquiry/Edit/Employer.vue'));

//instantiate root vue instance

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**Note:** do not mount root vue instance on the `body` element. Its better you create a wrapper element with some id like `#app` an mount the vue instance on this wrapper element.

This is not recommended in vue 2.0  which yeilds a warning. See [release notes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.3)

Comment: thank @Vamsi Krishna, but it didn't worked.. now it recognize vue.. but still can't find my components in my blade... what can i do?

Comment: @maral did you wrap the code with div element having id #app